# Using Oracles ODP.NET 12c Release 2 with Oracle 11g r2 Database

Tags: oracle, visual-studio-2013, odac

Our Oracle Db's are Oracle **11G r2,**. We use Visual Studio 2013 for development. Is ODAC 12C backwards compatible with the Oracle 11g r2 server? Are there any issues a developer will encounter using a newer ODAC /ODP.NET version than the database it's connecting to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the answer here:

http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ODPNT/InstallSystemRequirements.htm#ODPNT149

Access to Oracle Database 10g Release 2 or later